# Find out expression on a different sequential numbers

Tags: for-loop, expression

Question I am dealing with :
Assume that you have a variable called count that will take on the values 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on. You are going to formulate expressions in terms of count that will yield different sequences. For example, to get the sequence 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, ..., you would use the expression (2 * count). Fill in the following table, indicating an expression that will generate each sequence.

a. 2,4,6,8,10,12,...

b. 4,19,34,49,64,79,...

c. 30,20,10,0,-10,-20,...

d. -7,-3,1,5,9,13,...

e. 97,94,91,88,85,82,...

Answers are :

(a) 2 * count

(b) 15 * count – 11

(c) –10 * count + 40

(d) 4 * count – 11

(e) –3 * count + 100

I don't understand how did examiner generate the answers above.  For the question (a), I got it.  But the question (b) and beyond, I really don't get it where was 15 from.  Why suddenly 15?  And the next one even more difficult to understand where the -10 came from.  Would you help me how to get the answer step by step?  If I faced these questions again, I never want to miss them.  Thanks!

Comment: How is it related to Java?

Comment: How is this related to programming at all? Looks like you can solve this with some basic math...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic math. You can try http://math.stackexchange.com/ , but don't get your hopes up, because the answers are already in the question...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I edited tag Java as is not related to Java.  Ok I admited.

Comment: @jlordo Thanks for your comments.  From you advice, I found that I am having lack of competence for basic math.  It is good to look for math stuffs.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the difference between the numbers in the sequence to get the multiplier, then add or subtract so that the first term is correct.

For example:
5, 7, 9, 11

The difference is 2, but the starting number is 5, not 2, so +3.

Comment: Thanks I got your point.  I got clue now :-)